# How to abort a macports portfile on an error condition?

Tags: macports, tlc

I working on a version bump on the **cc65** and encountered a problem with the **linuxdoc-tools**. Since I can't fix the **linuxdoc-tools** and there is a simple workaround possible I decided to add an if statement to inform the user together with the workaround:

```
    if {! [file exists ${prefix}/bin/perl] } {
        ui_error "
«${prefix}/bin/perl» is missing but the linuxdoc-tools depends on it.

Please create an appropriate symbolic link for linuxdoc-tools to work.
"
    exit 1
    }
```

Crude but the best I can do since I'm neither the **perl5** nor the **linuxdoc-tools** maintainer and I don't want to spend to much time on a version bump.

However, the MacPorts doesn't understand `exit 1` and `ui_error` won't stop execution on its own.

How do I stop the execution so not to waste the users time on a build which will otherwise fail right at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `return -code error "error message"`, or the shorthand for the same thing, `error "error message"`.

Note that you should use `ui_error` before that to print a human-readable message for the user – while the error message is also being printed, it can sometimes get lost in the output.

Additionally, note that `$prefix/bin/perl` is a build dependency of `linuxdoc-tools`. If it is also needed at runtime, you should submit a pull request that adds `depends_run path:bin/perl:perl5` to the port rather than attempting to fix this bug in your port.

Comment: Good point on `linuxdoc-tools` — the dependency in perl should be runtime instead of buildtime — however that Port is **nomaintainer**. So if I write a ticket then there is one who will fix that problem.

Comment: For such a simple change, submitting a pull request is usually the quickest way to get this resolved. However, in this particular case, Ryan was faster anyway and fixed it already: https://github.com/macports/macports-ports/commit/8946a11ddc2e36b46de594975914f743cd7bb3a8